# Problem running nao_driver on cross-compiled Nao

Tags: ros, cross-compiling, nao-driver, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have cross-compiled ROS Groovy in my NAO V4, using this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Installation/local.
Now I'm following the instructions in here http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao_driver

But when I run the following command:

$ roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch

I get this error

```
... logging to /home/nao/.ros/log/fd173254-08e5-11e3-a0ff-243c2007c59c/roslaunch-Jarvis-3374.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is started roslaunch server http://Jarvis:54780/
SUMMARY
========
PARAMETERS

/rosdistro
/rosversion

NODES
/
nao_controller (nao_driver/nao_controller.py)
nao_sensors (nao_driver/nao_sensors.py)
nao_walker (nao_driver/nao_walker.py)
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3387]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
setting /run_id to fd173254-08e5-11e3-a0ff-243c2007c59c
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3400]
started core service [/rosout]
process[nao_walker-2]: started with pid [3412]
process[nao_sensors-3]: started with pid [3413]
process[nao_controller-4]: started with pid [3414]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/nao_driver/nao_walker.py", line 57, in 
from nao_driver.util import startWalkPose
ImportError: No module named util
================================================================================REQUIRED process [nao_walker-2] has died!
process has died [pid 3412, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nao_driver/nao_walker.py --pip=127.0.0.1 --pport=9559 __name:=nao_walker __log:=/home/nao/.ros/log/fd173254-08e5-11e3-a0ff-243c2007c59c/nao_walker-2.log].
log file: /home/nao/.ros/log/fd173254-08e5-11e3-a0ff-243c2007c59c/nao_walker-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
[nao_controller-4] killing on exit
[nao_sensors-3] killing on exit
[nao_walker-2] killing on exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/nao_driver/nao_sensors.py", line 44, in 
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/nao_driver/nao_controller.py", line 37, in 
import rospy
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rospy/init.py", line 49, in 
from nao_msgs.msg import TorsoOdometry, TorsoIMU
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nao_msgs/msg/init.py", line 29, in 
from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, 

File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rospy/client.py", line 51, in 
from ._BodyPoseActionResult import *
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nao_msgs/msg/_BodyPoseActionResult.py", line 1, in 
import roslib
"""autogenerated by genpy from nao_msgs/BodyPoseActionResult.msg. Do not edit."""
KeyboardInterrupt
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/roslib/init.py", line 54, in 
import roslib.stacks
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/roslib/stacks.py", line 46, in 
import roslib.packages
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 49, in 
from catkin.find_in_workspaces import find_in_workspaces as catkin_find
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py", line 36, in 
from catkin_pkg.packages import find_packages
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 38, in 
from .package import parse_package, PACKAGE_MANIFEST_FILENAME
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 48, in 
class Package(object):
KeyboardInterrupt
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

As you can see, it ask me to import util, and I don't know what it means or how to fix it.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73765/problem-running-nao_driver-on-cross-compiled-nao/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using the version provided with the binaries? Version 0.10 (which can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/ahornung/nao_robot/releases)) shouldn't have that issue.

The version that ships with the NAO v4 binaries hasn't yet been released and the commit that fixes your issue was only merged a few days ago.

We're currently working on a official release. You can either wait for it to be ready (which will hopefully happen soon) try installing version 0.10 (though I suspect v0.10 is not going to mix well with the binary installation) or just run version 0.10 remotely.

**Update**

The actual issue is that the scripts under `nao_driver/src/nao_driver/util` don't get installed, if you're in a hurry you can hack it to work by downloading the latest devel version and copying them by hand, eg:

```
$> git clone -b devel 'https://github.com/miguelsdc/nao_robot.git'
$> cp -r nao_robot/nao_driver/src/nao_driver/util/ /opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nao_driver/
```

You may need to use **sudo** in front of the last command.

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-08-19**:
I followed the instructions to install from binaries. I assume it uses that version you specify.
Does it have anything to do with the version of NaoQi I am using? It is the 1.14.3

**Comment by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on 2013-08-19**:
NaoQi 1.14.x should be fine. The version it uses it's *not* 0.10 (it's 0.11). And the bug was fixed on a commit that's not included in your version. I would suggest you wait a bit till we release the proper version, but if you're in a hurry read the updated answer...

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-08-20**:
Thank you I will try that and let know how it went

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-08-20**:
Miguel, should I just only copy the util/ folder or the whole src/ folder, which the commando would be:
$ cp -r /path/to/temp/dir/nao_robot/nao_driver/src/ src/

**Comment by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on 2013-08-20**:
Just the util folder (the src folder should be there already!)

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-08-21**:
Miguel, when I run:
Jarvis [0] ~ $ roscd nao_driver/
Jarvis [0] /opt/ros/groovy/share/nao_driver $ ls -a

; I get this output:
.  ..  cmake  launch  package.xml

I don't see any src folder

**Comment by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on 2013-08-21**:
True, my bad. I forgot the binaries get installed somewhere else... I've updated the instructions.

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-08-21**:
This is the new error I encountered:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/nao_driver/nao_controller.py", line 38, in 
import actionlib
ImportError: No module named actionlib

I guess there should be another scripts to transfer too

**Comment by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) on 2013-08-21**:
Nope, actionlib is a ROS core package and it should be installed on the robot. This looks like a bug we don't know about. Can you tell me what happens if you type roscd actionlib? Thanks!

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-08-27**:
There is no actionlib, using autocomplete with Tab Key, it says roscd actionlib_msgs.